# Python Nested Function Variable Scoping

Tags: python-3.x, variables, scope

I have the following functions:

```
def print_hamming_distance(calls):
    #calls is a dictionary
    samples = calls.keys() 
    with Pool(8) as pool: #Parallel Process
        for dist, sample1, sample2 in pool.imap(multi_proc_hamming_distance, itertools.combinations(samples,2)):
            print( dist, sample1, sample2 )   

def multi_proc_hamming_distance(samples): # specifically created function to use with pool
    return hamming_distance(calls[samples[0]],calls[samples[1]]), samples[0], samples[1]
```

When I call them in my code I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'calls' is not defined
```

I was under the impression that nested functions can access variables outside that function. Can someone explain to me why I'm getting this error?

I realize one of the solution is simply just passing the dictionary as an argument to the second function which was how I solved the problem but that increased the run time. Further, when I ran the code on jupyter without wrapping the print_hamming_distance(calls), it worked.

by without wrapping I mean like this :

```
def multi_proc_hamming_distance(samples): # specifically created function to use with pool
    return hamming_distance(calls[samples[0]],calls[samples[1]]), samples[0], samples[1]


#calls is already defined somewhere
samples = calls.keys() 
with Pool(8) as pool: #Parallel Process
    for dist, sample1, sample2 in pool.imap(multi_proc_hamming_distance, itertools.combinations(samples,2)):
        print( dist, sample1, sample2 )
```

Edit: Full Traceback error

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File             "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/some_env/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
File "/usr/project/pipeline/project_name/distance.py", line 44, in multi_proc_hamming_distance
return hamming_distance(calls[samples[0]],calls[samples[1]]), samples[0], samples[1]
NameError: name 'calls' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/project/pipeline/project_name.py", line 264, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/project/pipeline/project_name.py", line 259, in main
distance(param)
File "/usr/project/pipeline/project_name.py", line 169, in distance
distance = get_distance[param.data_type](calls)
File "/usr/project/pipeline/project_name/distance.py", line 37, in get_param_type_distance
for dist, sample1, sample2 in pool.imap(multi_proc_hamming_distance, itertools.combinations(samples,2)):
File "/home/usr/anaconda3/envs/some_env/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 731, in next
raise value
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback error?

Comment: Added the full traceback error as edit

Comment: check the answer, and see if the solution works now

Comment: There is no *lexical* nesting - you have a function that passes a second function to a third function. Their lexical environments are not related in any way. I suspect that you simply forgot to indent `multi_proc_hamming_distance`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think that was a just an editing error

Comment: @ikuamike I think it's difficult to tell - quite a few people expect dynamic scope rather than lexical.

Comment: @molbdnilo looking at the traceback error the only problem is `NameError: name 'calls' is not defined`

Comment: @ikuamike Yes, that happens if you call `multi_proc_hamming_distance` directly without nesting its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes nested functions can access variables outside that function. But in your case the calls variable is not defined inside the function it is only an argument and cannot be accessed by the nested function. You can correct that by adding `calls = calls` as follows.

```
def print_hamming_distance(calls):
    #calls is a dictionary
    calls = calls
    samples = calls.keys() 
    with Pool(8) as pool: #Parallel Process
    for dist, sample1, sample2 in pool.imap(multi_proc_hamming_distance, itertools.combinations(samples,2)):
        print( dist, sample1, sample2 )   

    # nested function
    def multi_proc_hamming_distance(calls,samples): # specifically created function to use with pool
        return hamming_distance(calls[samples[0]],calls[samples[1]]), samples[0], samples[1]
```

Comment: I've edited it so the nested functions receives the call

Comment: Is there really a need for `multi_proc_hamming_distance` since return calls a third function?

Comment: You are probably right that I can cut out the middle function but regardless I want to avoid adding the second argument. The second argument basically breaks pool.imap. Long story short, there is a way to circumvent using starmap or partial() function but the result is a longer run time as noted in the original post. In your opinion, is there any way that I can resolve this without adding a second argument

Comment: How about assigning `distance = hamming_distance(calls[samples[0]],calls[samples[1]])` then `return distance, samples[0], samples[1]` and you don't need `multi_proc_hamming_distance` and no second argument to add

Comment: I don't think that will work. What i can do is make a list of tupules with sample ids and the dictionary but at that point i might as well go back to my modified implementation. Thanks for helping